# SQL Server: set multiple values assigning them default

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SET @StartDate = NULL,
    @InitialLoopValue=NULL,
    @FinalLoopValue = NULL, @RootId = NULL, @MakeId = NULL, @CityId = NULL, 
    @CountOfCarsUpdated = NULL, @Url = NULL, @MakeName = NULL, @RootName = NULL, 
    @CityName = NULL, @Content = NULL, @SellInquiryId = NULL, @SellerType = NULL,@imei = NULL;
```

I have these many variables, and I get this error.

But when I put `SET` individually for each default assignment its working fine but that's too verbose.

How do I correct this?

Comment: while declaring variables you can assign value as well

Comment: `SET` by SQL syntax is for single assignment.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `SELECT` to assign multiple variables at once.

```
SELECT @StartDate = NULL,
       @InitialLoopValue=NULL,
       @FinalLoopValue = NULL, @RootId = NULL,
       @MakeId = NULL, @CityId = NULL, 
       @CountOfCarsUpdated = NULL, @Url = NULL,
       @MakeName = NULL, @RootName = NULL, 
       @CityName = NULL, @Content = NULL,
       @SellInquiryId = NULL, @SellerType = NULL,@imei = NULL;
```

---

Note: Default value for non-assigned variable is `NULL` so there is no need for `= NULL`.

```
DECLARE @v INT;
SELECT @v
-- NULL
```